# How to filter concatenated select options by custom attribute with JQuery

Tags: jquery, select

I would like to create two concatenated selects. The first select containes all the regions. The second one all the provinces. So when I select a region then I should visualize only the provinces located inside region.

This is my PHP code:

```
    echo "<br /><br />Region *<br />";
    $result = mysqli_query($link,$query_regione) ;
        echo "<select id='select_regioni' name='select_regioni' required>";
        echo "<option value='' ></option>";
        
                  //start cycle
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
                {
                    $regione_id=intval($row['reg_id']);
                    $regione_nome=$row['reg_nome'];
                    echo"<option value='$regione_id'>$regione_nome</option>";
                }
        echo "</select>"; 

        $query_provincie="SELECT distinct prov_id, prov_nome, com_idregione FROM `provincie` inner join comuni on prov_id = com_idprovincia WHERE 1";

        echo "<br />Province *<br />";
        $result = mysqli_query($link,$query_provincie) ;
            echo "<select id='select_provincie' name='select_provincie' required>";
            echo "<option value='' ></option>";
            
                      //start cycle
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
                    {
                        $provincia_id=intval($row['prov_id']);
                        $provincia_nome=$row['prov_nome'];
                        $regione_id=$row['com_idregione'];
                        echo"<option reg='$regione_id' value='$provincia_id'>$provincia_nome</option>";
                    }
            echo "</select>";
```

This is my Jquery listener:

```
$("#select_regioni").change(function(){
        var option = $('option:selected', this).attr('value');
        alert(option);
    });
```

As you can understand when I select in the first select an option with a value of 19, in the second select I should visualize only the options with the custom attribute `reg` equals to 19.
The Jquery listener shows exactly the value of the seclected option in the first select, but starting from this value how can I filter the second select? Is it possible to do that using JQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do something like that:

```
 $("option[reg]").hide(); //hide all option containning attribute reg
 $("option[reg='" + yournumregion + "']").show(); //show only option with reg=numregion
```

if you are sure all options region are not hidden by default, the 2 lines could be replaced by

```
 //hide all options which have not reg=numregion
 $("option:not([reg='" + yournumregion + "'])").hide();
```

---

```
$("#select_regioni").change(function(){
     var option = $('option:selected', this).attr('value');
     $("option[reg]").hide(); //hide all option containning attribute reg
     $("option[reg='" + option + "']").show(); //show only option with reg=numregion
     //$("option:not([reg='" + option + "'])").hide();
});
```